# Xcode 8: Cannot inherit class from the framework

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode8

After installing a framework into my project with Pod, I got the error message "Use of undeclared type ..." when I tried to create my own class by inheriting the class in the Library of the framework. But I can find the class in the Library by command-clicking the class in my file. Has anyone suffered from this problem before?

[image: Screenshot of Xcode error]

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import Former` (the module of the library you are using) to use its functions.

```
import UIKit
import Former  // <---

final class YourCell: UITableViewCell, LabelFormableRow {
    ...
```